# Modeling domain data in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm working on designing a larger-ish web application using Haskell. This is purely for my education and interest.

I'm starting by writing out my domain/value objects. One example is a User. Here's what I've come up with so far

```
module Model (User) where

class Audited a where
    creationDate :: a -> Integer
    lastUpdatedDate :: a -> Integer
    creationUser :: a -> User
    lastUpdatedUser :: a -> User

class Identified a where
    id :: a -> Integer

data User = User { userId :: Integer
                 , userEmail :: String
                 , userCreationDate :: Integer
                 , userLastUpdatedDate :: Integer
                 , userCreationUser :: User
                 , userLastUpdatedUser :: User
                 }

instance Identified User where
    id u = userId u 

instance Audited User where
    creationDate u = userCreationDate
    lastUpdatedDate u = userLastUpdatedDate
    creationUser u = userCreationUser
    lastUpdatedUser u = userLastUpdatedUser
```

My application will have roughly 20 types like the above type. When I say "like the above type", I mean they will have an id, audit information, and some type-specific information (like email in the case of User).

The thing I can't wrap my mind around is the fact that each of my fields (e.g. User.userEmail) creates a new function `fieldName :: Type -> FieldType`. With 20 different types, the namespace seems like it'll get pretty full pretty fast. Also, I don't like having to name my User ID field `userId`. I'd rather name it `id`. Is there any way around this?

Maybe I should mention that I'm coming from the imperative world, so this FP stuff is pretty new (yet pretty exciting) for me.

Comment: You can use the module system to control name scope and qualification.

Comment: Would this mean creating a module for each type and doing an `import qualified Model.User as User` (for example)?

Comment: Oh, just using `import qualified` to control the record label field explosion problem.

Comment: Note that `id` is a bad choice for a function name; it's [defined in the Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:id) to be the identity function.  (`id :: a -> a`, `id x = x`)

Comment: @Antal S-Z: I agree, but `id` is conventionally used for object id's in persisted data.  I think it's reasonable to go either way in resolving the conflict.

Comment: @John, because of `id` being in the Haskell Prelude, I usually use `ident`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, namespacing can be kind of a pain in Haskell.  I usually end up tightening up my abstractions until there are not so many names.  It also allows for more reuse.  For yours, I would make a data type rather than a class for the audit information:

```
data Audit = Audit {
    creationDate :: Integer,
    lastUpdatedDate :: Integer,
    creationUser :: User,
    lastUpdatedUser :: User
}
```

And then pair that up with the type-specific data:

```
data User = User { 
    userAudit :: Audit,
    userId :: Integer,
    userEmail :: String
}
```

You can still use those typeclasses if you want:

```
class Audited a where
    audit :: a -> Audit

class Identified a where
    ident :: a -> Integer
```

However as your design develops, be open to the possibility of those typeclasses dissolving into thin air.  *Object-like* typeclasses -- ones where every method takes a single parameter of type `a` -- have a way of simplifying themselves away.

Another way to approach this might be to classify your objects with a parametric type:

```
data Object a = Object {
    objId    :: Integer,
    objAudit :: Audit,
    objData  :: a
}
```

Check it out, `Object` is a `Functor`!

```
instance Functor Object where
    fmap f (Object id audit dta) = Object id audit (f dta)
```

I would be more inclined to do it this way, based on my design hunch.  It is hard to say which way is better without knowing more about your plans.  And look, the need for those typeclasses dissolved away.  :-)

Comment: In line with Robin Green's comment, absolutely look into lenses (`data-accessor` or `fclabels` on hackage) for working with records of records (of records ...).

Answer (score 8):

This is a known problem with Haskell's records.  There have been some suggestions (notably [TDNR](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/TypeDirectedNameResolution)) to mitigate the effects, but no solutions have emerged yet.

If you don't mind putting each of your data objects in a separate module, then you can use namespaces to differentiate between the functions:

```
import qualified Model.User as U
import qualified Model.Privileges as P

someUserId user = U.id user
somePrivId priv = P.id priv
```

As to using `id` instead of `userId`; it's possible if you hide the `id` which is imported from the Prelude by default.  Use the following as your first import statement:

```
import Prelude hiding (id)
```

and now the usual `id` function won't be in scope.  If you need it for some reason, you can access it with a fully-qualified name, i.e. `Prelude.id`.

Think carefully before creating a name that clashes with the Prelude.  It can often be confusing for the programmer, and it's slightly awkward to work with.  You may be better off using short, generic name, such as `oId`.

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is, rather than going all out on type classes, make all your types varieties of a single algebraic data type:

```
data DomainObject = User {
                      objectID :: Int,
                      objectCreationDate :: Date
                      ...
                    }
                  | SomethingElse {
                      objectID :: Int,
                      objectCreationDate :: Date,
                      somethingProperty :: Foo
                      ...
                    }
                  | AnotherThing {
                      objectID :: Int,
                      objectCreationDate :: Date,
                      anotherThingProperty :: Bar
                      ...
                    }
```

It's clunky because it requires having all your data structures in a single file, but it does at least allow you to use the same function (`objectID`) to get the ID of an object.

Comment: Because everything here has an ID and a creation date, it would make sense to package those two things up into a common data type. I have a feeling lenses might be useful here.

Comment: @Robin Green - where can I find an example of lenses being used? I found this: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lenses, but there's no example. Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I found this: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lenses/0.1.4/doc/html/Data-Lenses.html