# Name conflicts in Haskell records

Tags: haskell

Haskell doesn't have dot notation for record members. For each record member a compiler creates a function with the same name with a type  RecType -> FieldType. This leads to name conflicts. Are there any ways to work around this, i.e. how can I have several records with the same field names?

Comment: Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775068/modeling-domain-data-in-haskell/5777042#5777042

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922437/   and: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677834/

Comment: This may be fixed Real Soon Now in GHC. I think its a GSoC project :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another way to avoid this problem is to use the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package. It provides a makeFields template haskell function, which you can use like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances   #-}
import           Control.Lens

data A = A
  { _aText :: String
  }
makeFields ''A   -- Creates a lens x for each record accessor with the name _aX

data B = B
  { _bText  :: Int
  , _bValue :: Int
  }
-- Creates a lens x for each record accessor with the name _bX
makeFields ''B  

main = do
  let a = A "hello"
  let b = B 42 1

  -- (^.) is a function of lens which accesses a field (text) of some value (a)
  putStrLn $ "Text of a: " ++ a ^. text 
  putStrLn $ "Text of b: " ++ show (b ^. text)
```

If you don't want to use TemplateHaskell and lens, you can also do manually what lens automates using TemplateHaskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances   #-}
data A = A
  { aText :: String
  }

data B = B
  { bText  :: Int
  , bValue :: Int
  }

-- A class for types a that have a "text" field of type t
class HasText a t | a -> t where

  -- An accessor for the text value
  text :: a -> t

-- Make our two types instances of those
instance HasText A String where text = aText
instance HasText B Int where text = bText

main = do
  let a = A "hello"
  let b = B 42 1
  putStrLn $ "Text of a: " ++ text a
  putStrLn $ "Text of b: " ++ show (text b)
```

But I can really recommend learning lens, as it also provides lots of other utilities, like modifying or setting a field.

Comment: This does not work if two fields have the same name but different types.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez At least the lens version works for different types. I didn't want to complicate the manual version with Type families or functional dependencies so I left out the different types thing.

Comment: Ok, actually, it's not that difficult so I added support for different types.

Comment: Note: the declared field name should have the name of the data type in camel case in front. For example:
data ThingA = ThingA {_thingAName :: String}

Answer (score 23):

For large projects, I prefer to keep each type in its own module and use Haskell's module system to namespace accessors for each type.

For example, I might have some type `A` in module `A`:

```
-- A.hs

data A = A
    { field1 :: String
    , field2 :: Double
    }
```

... and another type `B` with similarly-named fields in module `B`:

```
-- B.hs

data B = B
    { field1 :: Char
    , field2 :: Int
    }
```

Then if I want to use both types in some other module `C` I can import them qualified to distinguish which accessor I mean:

```
-- C.hs
import A as A
import B as B

f :: A -> B -> (Double, Int)
f a b = (A.field2 a, B.field2 b)
```

Unfortunately, Haskell does not have a way to define multiple name-spaces within the same module, otherwise there would be no need to split each type in a separate module to do this.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid It's not that awkward. In fact this approach is pretty common in other languages, e.g., in Java each type (class or interface) has to be located in a separate file.

Answer (score 9):

The GHC developers developed a couple of extensions to help with this issue . Check out [this ghc wiki page](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/records/overloaded-record-fields). Initially a single `OverloadedRecordFields` extension was planned, but instead two extensions were developed. The extensions are [OverloadedLabels](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=overloadedlabels#extension-OverloadedLabels) and [DuplicateRecordFields](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=overloadedlabels#extension-DuplicateRecordFields). Also see [that reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/8693a3/usefulness_of_duplicaterecordfields/).

The DuplicateRecordFields extensions makes this code legal in a single module:

```hs
data Person  = MkPerson  { personId :: Int, name :: String }
data Address = MkAddress { personId :: Int, address :: String }
```

As of 2019, I'd say these two extensions didn't get the adoption I thought they would have (although they did get some adoption) and the status quo is probably still ongoing.

Comment: What happened to this plan?

Comment: @DerekMahar I updated the answer with more recent information!

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Do you have the link to the plan?  The "this plan" link is broken.

Comment: I updated again the answer to remove the dead link and put some more info. If you're interested in the history of the feature, I recommend checking the "history" section of the ghc wiki page, and also "Original design" link on that page.