# What's the difference between makeLenses and makeFields?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Pretty self-explanatory. I know that `makeClassy` should create typeclasses, but I see no difference between the two.

*PS. Bonus points for explaining the default behaviour of both.*

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478599/name-conflicts-in-haskell-records) *might* answer it, as in that `Fields` makes the name-based classes, and `Lenses` does not, but I have no idea how to verify that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Note: This answer is based on lens 4.4 or newer. There were some changes to the TH in that version, so I don't know how much of it applies to older versions of lens.*

#### Organization of the lens TH functions

The lens TH functions are all based on one function, `makeLensesWith` (also named `makeFieldOptics` inside lens). This function takes a `LensRules` argument, which describes exactly what is generated and how.

So to compare `makeLenses` and `makeFields`, we only need to compare the `LensRules` that they use. You can find them by looking at the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.4.0.1/docs/src/Control-Lens-TH.html):

#### makeLenses

```
lensRules :: LensRules
lensRules = LensRules
  { _simpleLenses    = False
  , _generateSigs    = True
  , _generateClasses = False
  , _allowIsos       = True
  , _classyLenses    = const Nothing
  , _fieldToDef      = \_ n ->
       case nameBase n of
         '_':x:xs -> [TopName (mkName (toLower x:xs))]
         _        -> []
  }
```

#### makeFields

```
defaultFieldRules :: LensRules
defaultFieldRules = LensRules
  { _simpleLenses    = True
  , _generateSigs    = True
  , _generateClasses = True  -- classes will still be skipped if they already exist
  , _allowIsos       = False -- generating Isos would hinder field class reuse
  , _classyLenses    = const Nothing
  , _fieldToDef      = camelCaseNamer
  }
```

#### What do these mean?

Now we know that the differences are in the `simpleLenses`, `generateClasses`, `allowIsos` and `fieldToDef` options. But what do those options actually mean?

- `makeFields` will never generate type-changing optics. This is controlled by the `simpleLenses = True` option. That option doesn't have haddocks in the current version of lens. However, lens HEAD added documentation for it:

  ```
   -- | Generate "simple" optics even when type-changing optics are possible.
   -- (e.g. 'Lens'' instead of 'Lens')
  ```

  So `makeFields` will never generate type-changing optics, while `makeLenses` will if possible.
- `makeFields` will generate classes for the fields. So for each field `foo`, we have a class:

  ```
  class HasFoo t where
    foo :: Lens' t <Type of foo field>
  ```

  This is controlled by the `generateClasses` option.
- `makeFields` will never generate `Iso`'s, even if that would be possible (controlled by the `allowIsos` option, which doesn't seem to be exported from `Control.Lens.TH`)
- While `makeLenses` simply generates a top-level lens for each field that starts with an underscore (lowercasing the first letter after the underscore), `makeFields` will instead generate instances for the `HasFoo` classes. It also uses a different naming scheme, explained in a comment in the source code:

  ```
  -- | Field rules for fields in the form @ prefixFieldname or _prefixFieldname @
  -- If you want all fields to be lensed, then there is no reason to use an @_@ before the prefix.
  -- If any of the record fields leads with an @_@ then it is assume a field without an @_@ should not have a lens created.
  camelCaseFields :: LensRules
  camelCaseFields = defaultFieldRules
  ```

  So `makeFields` also expect that all fields are not just prefixed with an underscore, but also include the data type name as a prefix (as in `data Foo = { _fooBar :: Int, _fooBaz :: Bool }`). If you want to generate lenses for all fields, you can leave out the underscore.

  This is all controlled by the `_fieldToDef` (exported as `lensField` by `Control.Lens.TH`).

As you can see, the `Control.Lens.TH` module is very flexible. Using `makeLensesWith`, you can create your very own `LensRules` if you need a pattern not covered by the standard functions.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: this is based on experimenting with the working code; it gave me enough information to proceed with my project, but I'd still prefer a better-documented answer.*

```
data Stuff = Stuff {
    _foo
    _FooBar
    _stuffBaz
}
```

### `makeLenses`

- Will create `foo` as a lens accessor to `Stuff`
- Will create `fooBar` (changing the capitalized name to lowercase);

### `makeFields`

- Will create `baz` and a class `HasBaz`; it will make `Stuff` an instance of that class.

Answer (score 3):

### Normal

`makeLenses` creates a single top-level optic for each field in the type. It looks for fields that start with an underscore (`_`) and it creates an optic that is as general as possible for that field.

- If your type has one constructor and one field you'll get an `Iso`.
- If your type has one constructor and multiple fields you'll get many `Lens`.
- If your type has multiple constructors you'll get many `Traversal`.

### Classy

`makeClassy` creates a single class containing all the optics for your type. This version is used to make it easy to embed your type in another larger type achieving a kind of subtyping. `Lens` and `Traversal` optics will be created according to the rules above (`Iso` is excluded because it hinders the subtyping behavior.)

In addition to one method in the class per field you'll get an extra method that makes it easy to derive instances of this class for other types. All of the other methods have default instances in terms of the top-level method.

```
data T = MkT { _field1 :: Int, _field2 :: Char }

class HasT a where
  t :: Lens' a T
  field1 :: Lens' a Int
  field2 :: Lens' a Char

  field1 = t . field1
  field2 = t . field2

instance HasT T where
  t = id
  field1 f (MkT x y) = fmap (\x' -> MkT x' y) (f x)
  field2 f (MkT x y) = fmap (\y' -> MkT x y') (f y)

data U = MkU { _subt :: T, _field3 :: Bool }

instance HasT U where
  t f (MkU x y) = fmap (\x' -> MkU x' y) (f x)
  -- field1 and field2 automatically defined
```

This has the additional benefit that it is easy to export/import all the lenses for a given type. `import Module (HasT(..))`

### Fields

`makeFields` creates a single class per field which is intended to be reused between all types that have a field with the given name. This is more of a solution to record field names not being able to be shared between types.