# Trouble writing readable code using Haskell records

Tags: haskell

I'm fairly new to Haskell, and one thing I've been struggling with is writing readable code using records.

My specific problems are:

1. I haven't found an effective strategy for dealing with name conflicts between fields in different record types.  I'm finding I want the same field in multiple different record types, and the name conflict issue is really annoying.  I end up choosing some prefix to put on all of my fields, which adds to verbosity and hinders readability.
2. Using nested records results in really verbose code.  I find
   `someFunction(foo.bar, 2 * foo.bar.baz)`
   in a language like Java or C++ to be pretty readable.  In Haskell I find myself writing this to accomplish the same thing
   `someFunction (fooBar foo) (2 * barBaz (fooBar foo))`
   which is a lot harder to visually parse, and calls to functions with multiple arguments quickly become unreadable.  In order to make this more readable, I find myself defining intermediate values which are to extract fields from records, which is more readable, but adds more lines of code, so it hurts readability in a different way.

Is there a better way to use records that is more readable, or is there something I should be doing instead?  Just using tuples?  Writing functions with tons of parameters instead of grouping related values into records?  Something else?

Comment: Point #1 is, as far as I know, a known bad aspect of Haskell records. At least some languages get around this by requiring you to use namespaces for record field accessor functions. I'm sure there are other solutions too. As to point #2, I think this is where the Lens library starts becoming useful.

Comment: Regarding 1), I'm not sure anyone has :) [This](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields) might help, especially the `DuplicateRecordFields` extension. Regarding 2), [lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-tutorial-1.0.3/docs/Control-Lens-Tutorial.html) may help.

Comment: With respect to #1, both answers to [*Name conflicts in Haskell records*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17478599/2751851) are relevant.

Comment: I don't find I want to do nested record access very often; usually I will have pattern matched above. In addition to above suggestions I really like the `RecordWildCards` extension: it would let you do: `outerFunc Foo{..} =  ...  someFunction fooBar (2 * barBaz fooBar)`

Answer (score 2):

One solution (as suggested in the comments) to the problem is to use lenses. Using the `microlens` and `microlens-th` packages (these might be simpler when you're getting started):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.List (nub)
import Lens.Micro ((^.), (^..))
import Lens.Micro.TH (makeFields)

newtype Name = Name String
  deriving Eq

data Person = Person { _personName :: Name }
makeFields ''Person

data Species = Dog | Cat
  deriving Eq

data Pet = Pet { _petName :: Name, _petSpecies :: Species }
makeFields ''Pet

-- ^. is an infix operator for view
uniquePersonNames :: [Person] -> [Name]
uniquePersonNames ps = nub (map (\p -> p ^. name) ps)

dogs :: [Pet] -> [Pet]
dogs ps = filter (\p -> p ^. species == Dog) ps

data Concert = Concert
  { _concertPerformers :: [Person]
  , _concertAttendees :: [Person]
  }
makeFields ''Concert

-- ^.. is an infix operator for toListOf
performerNames :: Concert -> [Name]
performerNames c = c ^.. performers . traverse . name

data House = House { _housePeople :: [Person], _housePet :: Pet}
makeFields ''House

houseSound :: House -> String
houseSound h = case h ^. pet . species of
    Dog -> "Woof!"
    Cat -> "Meow!"
```

There are several resources out there to learn more about lenses and other kinds of optics. One particularly beginner friendly resource [Control.Lens.Tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-tutorial-1.0.3/docs/Control-Lens-Tutorial.html).

Be warned that this approach can lead to type errors that are hard to understand (I believe the `generic-lens` library has better error messages, but I have not used it), especially if you start using things blindly. I suggest sticking to the basics (as presented in the linked tutorial) -- this will cover a large portion of your use cases.