# How can I refactor duplicate field names in Haskell data types?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a data structure that describes items on my CV, just to learn about Haskell and its data types. Here's what I have so far:

```
data Update = Talk { date :: Date,
                     pubTitle :: Text,
                     url :: URI,
                     venue :: Text
                   }
            | Publication { date :: Date,
                            pubTitle :: Text,
                            venue :: Venue,
                            pubType :: PublicationType
                          }
            | Award { date :: Date,
                      award :: Text,
                      awardedBy :: Link
                    }
            | News { date :: Date, desc :: Markdown }
            deriving Show


data PublicationType = Tutorial | Article | Chapter | Abstract
```

This won't work, apparently, since Haskell thinks I have multiple declarations of `date` and so on. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478599/name-conflicts-in-haskell-records) where an answer suggests using an extension, but I tried adding `{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}` to the top of my file, and it doesn't seem to help—I'm getting the same errors.

I suspect that there's a way to refactor these records in some way, no? Or maybe I should be doing something different entirely to convey this kind of data structure.

Comment: "Haskell thinks I have multiple declarations of `date` " If you'd shown the error message, you'd see the problem is _not_ multiple declarations of `date`, but multiple declarations of `venue` at different types. Multiple `date` is OK providing they're the same field type; `DuplicateRecordFields` isn't needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach you could take would be to factor out the duplication:

```
data Update = Update Date Event                                                 

data Event = News Markdown                                                      
           | Award Text Link                                                    
           | Artifact { title :: Text                                           
                      , venue :: Venue                                          
                      , artifact :: Accomplishment                              
                      }                                                         

data Accomplishment = Talk URI                                                  
                    | Publication PublicationType
```

Here I've used record syntax for the Artifact constructor, but I'm not convinced it's the best approach. The partial accessors it creates are pretty gross; I just used it because it's otherwise not clear what the Text field means. You could clear this up using non-record syntax by defining a newtype around Text, or a type alias; or you could add a named Artifact type that contains the same thing, with the Artifact constructor just holding an Artifact.

Answer (score 2):

Even with `DuplicateRecordFields`, you can't have two record fields with the same name on different data constructors of the same type if their types are different. In this case, the problem is that you have `venue :: Text` for `Talk`, but `venue :: Venue` for `Publication`. Either change one of their types or rename one of them. To understand why this restriction is necessary, think about what type the `venue` record selector function must be.

Also, it's generally a bad idea to use records on types that have more than one constructor (except in the edge case where all of the fields are the same), because it causes partiality. For example, doing `awardedBy (News foo bar)` will crash your program.

Comment: If it's a bad idea to use records in data structures like this, what would be a better way of writing it?

Comment: There are 2 solutions that I see: 1) do the same but without records, ie `data Update = Talk Date Text URI Text | Publication Date Text Venue PublicationType | ...` (and note that this doesn't stop you making convenience functions such as `date :: Update -> Date`, by simple pattern matching, 2) still use records, but make 4 different types, then make `Update` a sum type over them all. (Again you can still make convenience functions where the types allow, and this way you still get the benefits of records, but only for the individual components of the sum type, which avoids partial functions.)

Comment: @Jonathan Very often with this type of data structure you'll end up wanting to write functions that deal specifically with one of the "subtypes" separately (e.g. something that takes a list of publications, not a list of any kind of update). That forces you to either factor out the constructor into its own type anyway, or else write fragile code that *can* be passed any updates but is only *supposed* to be passed publications. A lot of the time it's just easier to default to "sum types should have at most one field per constructor, records should have only one constructor".

Comment: @Ben "sum types should have at most one field per constructor" I don't agree with this part. Applied to lists, that would mean you'd need `data List a = Nil | Cons (NonEmpty a)` `data NonEmpty a = NonEmpty { head :: a, tail :: List a }`. In general, it means that every recursive type that isn't always infinite would need to be split into a pair of mutually recursive types. I also don't see the harm in having multiple fields as long as the multiple fields don't have record selectors.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That's a good point. I was sort of intending my "a lot of the time" weasel words to cover that, but I was still really overstating it. I think there's a distinction in my mind between simple "structural" types like lists etc, and "business model" types like those in the OP. It's the latter where I find you almost inevitably end up wanting the sum-components as separate types (whether or not you used record syntax).

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Though I guess it's worth noting that even the `NonEmpty` you suggested to criticise the idea has ended up being useful enough to exist in base! https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html

Comment: @Ben Yes, but my point was that `[]` isn't defined in terms of `NonEmpty`.